# How to convert TCHAR to const char?

Tags: c++, char, constants, tchar

The most similar thing I found is conversion to char. I'm trying to convert TCHAR "path" to const char. Btw I use character set: "Not Set".

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// ... your defines
#define MAX_LEN 100

TCHAR *systemDrive = getenv("systemDrive");
TCHAR path[_MAX_PATH];
_tcscpy(path, systemDrive);

TCHAR c_wPath[MAX_LEN] = _T("Hello world!");//this is original
//TCHAR c_wPath[MAX_LEN] = path; "path" shows error
char c_szPath[MAX_LEN];

wcstombs(c_szPath, c_wPath, wcslen(c_wPath) + 1);
```

Comment: `TCHAR` is not a type. It as a define to either `wchar_t`, or `char`, depending on whether `UNICODE` macro is defined. In the current age - it is leftover for backwards compatibility, you are better off with sticking with either `wchar_t`, or to `char`.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Aišku, o gal žinote kaip konvertuoti į const char?

Comment: @Hurricane It could be very polite if you'd stick to English!!

Comment: I try const char PATH[] = path and I get error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char [260]' to 'const char []'

Comment: @Swordfish Sorry, I can't edit first comment

Comment: char const * path = path

Comment: Hmm, now I get error C2372: 'path' : redefinition; different types of indirection

Comment: @Hurricane char const * PATH = path

Comment: @Swordfish It's working, thank you!

Comment: @Hurricane Stop playing with WinAPI and rather get a book to learn the languate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCHAR is alias for different types depending of platform, defined macros, etc.
so, TCHAR can be alias for char(1 byte) or WCHAR(2 bytes). 
further, WCHAR can be alias for wchar_t or unsigned short.
But, you made conversion using wcstombs which has signature like
`size_t wcstombs(char *,  const wchar_t *,  size_t)`,
so you have

```
char* c_szPath
```

pointing to converted array of char,
now, if you need const char*, it is probably enough to write simply
`const char * myPath = c_szPath`, it is legal, and use myPath.
But maybe, you even don't need this, because char* can bind on argument of type
const char * if you need to pass it to function as argument.
When you say,

> "path" shows error

that is because array type is not assignable.
I really hope this helps.